# Changing from system() to exec(), does it speed up my code?

Tags: c, linux, embedded, embedded-linux

I need to execute some Linux command line in my C code so I choose to use `system()`. Unfortunately, it place in `while(1)` and maybe it make my program slow down. Does it improve if I use `exec()` family? If yes, could you show me how to convert this line from `system()` to `exec()?`

```
while(1) {
........
system("echo \"x = 800 , y = 480 , swap = swap_32_16\"> /sys/bus/platform/drivers/display/layer0");
........
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Well the `system` function usually starts a shell to execute the command (with `fork` and `exec`), and unless the shell has the command `echo` built-in it in turn have to do a `fork` and `exec` to execute the command. That's two `fork` and `exec` calls to run the command. You can do it with only one each. However, if you do it yourself then you have to set up the file descriptors to handle the redirection yourself, so it's going to be more code. And more code means more complexity and more chances of bugs.

Comment: Lastly, if you're really curious, then *test it!* Do each variant a lot of times, and measure the attempts to get an average that you can compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could use POSIX `open()`/`write()`/`close()` for even less overhead (assuming your C compiler/runtime environment provides them):

```
static char data[] = "x = 800 , y = 480 , swap = swap_32_16\n";
int fd = open( "/sys/bus/platform/drivers/display/layer0", O_WRONLY );
write( fd, data, strlen( data ) );
close( fd );
```

Proper headers and all error checking have been omitted for brevity.

Comment: well in this case it is less overhead but as soon as you start formatting stuff the system calls will again have more ;)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I doubt that. The echo command may be lightweight when issued from the shell or shell script, but an entire command shell is being launched just to execute it from C code on every iteration.

Comment: @Clifford ah, I am contrasting this against my answer

Answer (score 10):

The `exec*` equivalent of

```
system("echo \"x = 800 , y = 480 , swap = swap_32_16\">"
       "/sys/bus/platform/drivers/display/layer0");
```

is something like

```
execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", "echo \"x = 800 , y = 480,"
      " swap = swap_32_16\">/sys/bus/platform/drivers/display/layer0", (char*)NULL);
```

The problem is that it is the **exact** same command that `system` would execute (in a newly forked subprocess), only more to type. And since `exec` **replaces** the current process with the newly executed program, the `exec` call would be the last one your program executes, unless you `fork()` the process first... and handle failures and and... wait for the completion of the subprocess etc.

---

The **true solution** of course is to not use an external command at all, just do that in C:

```
FILE *f = fopen("/sys/bus/platform/drivers/display/layer0", "w");
if (!f) { 
    // ... could not open ... 
}
fputs("x = 800 , y = 480 , swap = swap_32_16\n", f);
fclose(f);
```

Comment: Thank you, It good idea, but i don't know why, it doesn't work with fopen(), fputs() but work corretly with open(), write()

Comment: Interestinh. Then do use open+write